# Only get the H+W geometry of my screen without the later +x+y

Tags: command-line, awk

I am reading this [article](http://www.wikihow.com/Record-Your-Desktop-Using-FFmpeg-on-Ubuntu-Linux). There is a statement there that goes:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:0,0 -f x11grab -s $(xwininfo -root | grep 'geometry' | awk '{print $2;}') -r 25 -i :0.0 -sameq -f mpeg -ar 48000 -s wvga -y sample.mp4
```

When I run the command I get an error with the section that says:

```
xwininfo -root | grep 'geometry' | awk '{print $2;}'
```

The reason is that when you use this command on my computer it outputs:

```
1360x768+0+0
```

How do I remove the last part of the screen resolution output to be `1360x768` instead of `1360x768+0+0`?

Comment: If you know the geometry, 1360x768, just use rather then a variable

Comment: I realize this, and already did it this way successfully. But I was trying to use the experience to increase my awk knowledge as well. :)

Comment: OK, good luck. There are several excellent tutorials on awk on the internet.

Answer (score 10):

- You can use `perl` to get only the resolution:

  ```
  xwininfo -root | perl -lne 's/.*geometry (\w+).*/$1/ or next; print'
  1360x768
  ```
- Or even shorter with just GNU `grep`:

  ```
  xwininfo -root | grep -oP '(?<=geometry )\w+'
  1360x768
  ```

  **Explanation**: The lookbehind `(?<=geometry )` asserts that at the current position in the string, what precedes is the characters "geometry ". If the assertion succeeds, the engine matches the resolution pattern.

  A lookbehind does not "consume" any characters on the string. This means that after the closing parenthesis, the regex engine is left standing on the very same spot in the string from which it started looking: it hasn't moved. From that position, then engine can start matching characters again.

  Source: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookbehind

Comment: @Guest123ABC I've updated my answer with a shorter version of the regular expression

Answer (score 6):

My pure `awk` approach, splitting the string into fields based on spaces and plus signs:

```
xwininfo -root | awk -F'[+| ]' '/geometry/ {print $4}'
```

A similar method to Sylvain's Perl expression but with `sed`:

```
xwininfo -root | sed -nr 's/.*geometry ([0-9x]+).*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 5):

You could maybe use `awk` `substr`. In your particular case :

```
xwininfo -root | awk '/geometry/ {print substr($2,1,8);}'
```

Or if you want it to work in any case :

```
xwininfo -root | awk '/geometry/ {print $2;}' | cut -d'+' -f1
```

hope this help.

Comment: Oh yes! Thank you very much! The first one worked! :) The second one produces two results: a 1 and then the resolution which would not work in this case, but still a cool statement for general knowledge.

Comment: you should use the answer from sylvain. it's nicer.

Comment: I've moved the grep portion into the awk command (because I can't help myself). The problem with substr is it uses fixed placements. Resolutions like 1000x1000 will break it because they're too long.

Comment: @Oli wow nice move. i'll not forget about that grep replacement. Thanks for the tips. You totally right about the substr, this is why i added the second command.

Answer (score 2):

Others have already provided answers for the complete operation, but to answer only *How do I get from `1360x768+0+0` to `1360x768`?* then I would recomment using `cut` as the simplest possible solution, e.g.

```
$ echo 1360x768+0+0 | cut -d+ -f1
1360x768
$
```

Answer (score 1):

I also tried command line screen capture examples a few weeks ago. As an alternative solution you can use

```
 xdpyinfo  | grep dimensions | awk -F ' ' ' { print $2 } '
```

for detecting screen resolution.

To capture screen with internal audio and microphone, you can use

```
 avconv -f   pulse -i default -f x11grab -r 15 -s $(xdpyinfo  | grep dimensions | awk -F ' ' ' { print $2 } ' ) -i :0.0+0,0 -acodec libmp3lame -vcodec libx264  $(date +"%m%d%Y_%H%M%S_$HOSTNAME")_screencast.mp4
```